# PayPal Checkout - can we send funds to another person?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We have been using the **PayPal Checkout (v4)** for a little while now, and really like the way it integrates. This is the system I'm talking about:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/checkout-flow/

We are using this plugin to do the magic:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout

Anyway, as I said we have this all working fine when someone is sending *US* the money. However, we also have a tool on our site where "customers" can send money to sellers. For this, we currently have the *Adaptive Payments* system.

**My question:** How can we use the PayPal Checkout tool to let people send to a given email address, while still getting the callback for the order? (so we can enter it into our system, to track it)

At first I thought this wouldn't be possible - but I've seen this exact same logic on eBay:

[image]

Is this something that is publicly available? Or is it just a "PayPal-Ebay" thing? (as they are effectively the same company, so maybe have access to different tools than the general public do)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option -- the `payee` option in PayPal's REST api:

https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/

Using this, you can set the money to be moved to whichever paypal account you like with just the email address.

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal Express Checkout v4 is based on [PayPal Rest API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/) which does not support spliting or sending payment to a given PayPal account that is not the API caller. Adaptive payment is the right to do so in PayPal. The PayPal checkout on eBay is only for eBay, the checkout experience may look similar but it's using different product than the Express Checkout v4.

Comment: Ah ok, I had a feeling that may be the case :( Worth asking though, as it's a nicer experience. Maybe in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The basic integration lets you set up a button for a merchant using only their client id:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/

So if you can collect the merchant's client id, you can set up a button to make payments to that merchant.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's a good way to send payment to a given PayPal account! But the asynchronous notifications to update order system like [webhook](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/#integration-steps) or IPN may not work in this case, and needs to rely on the return of `action.payment.execute()` to get the payment result.

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately the end user would also not be up to working out getting client id's... they are pretty un-tech-savvy :(

Comment: Just wanted to ping again. I'm on the team that works on this integration, so it would be awesome to know what your use-case is so we can figure out a good way to support you. Thanks!

Comment: (Also feel free to raise questions on the github repo itself, we're more likely to see them there)